# In some device in china not found package for GCM Registeration

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

com.google.android.gsf package couldn't be found

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.innowaystimesheet, PID: 1309
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf
at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(GCMRegistrar.java:98)
at com.innowaystimesheet.LoginActivity.registerGCM(LoginActivity.java:217)  at com.innowaystimesheet.LoginActivity.access$0(LoginActivity.java:215)
atcom.innowaystimesheet.LoginActivity$1.handleMessage(LoginActivity.java:5
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can we add package in app side or any other way to resolve??

Answer (score 1):

> can we add package in app side or any other way to resolve??

If device doesn't have that package then before register you should check whether device supports GCM or have updated google play services app in device.

If not then you can give dialog to user that google play servce is required for GCM push notification and redirect user to play store with google play services package. From there once user download it then your problem should be solved.

Comment: but it using android 4.4 kitkat

Comment: @Dilavar I'm not sure what you mean of "using android 4.4"

Comment: @Dilavar It doesn't matter what device you have, if you are using GCM in your project then google play services is must. Some users sometime manually uninstall google play services so this can be reason also for this error.

Answer (score 0):

> can we add package in app side or any other way to resolve??

**Yes You can.**

Open your SDK folder and inside it

```
your-android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\
```

and then

```
Client code to be used in Android app :
 gcm\gcm-client\
```

Copy gcm.jar to your project's libs folder and add it to build path and you are done.Hope it will help.Thanks